# Junit testing for database conection

Tags: junit4, powermockito

Is there a way to test below code.Here I am connecting to database with JNDI.I am new to mockito and not getting a way to test the same.

```
    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
public Connection getJNDIConnection() {
    Connection result = null;
    try {
        InitialContext initialContext = new InitialContext();
        if (initialContext == null) {
            LOGGER.info("JNDI problem. Cannot get InitialContext.");
        }
        DataSource datasource = (DataSource) initialContext.lookup(jndiName);
        if (datasource != null) {
            result = datasource.getConnection();
        } else {
            LOGGER.info("Failed to lookup datasource.");
        }
    } catch (NamingException ex) {
        LOGGER.error("Cannot get connection: " + ex);
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        LOGGER.error("Cannot get connection: " + ex);
    }
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Of course, you can to do it, but I think you should read the documentation yourself. The main points here is:

```
InitialContext initialContext = mock(InitialContext.class);
DataSource dataSource = mock(DataSource.class);
Connection expected = mock(Connection.class);

whenNew(InitialContext.class).withNoArguments().thenReturn(initialContext);
when(initialContext.lookup(jndiName)).thenReturn(dataSource);
when(initialContext.getConnection()).thenReturn(connection);

Connection result = intatnceOfCalss.getJNDIConnection();

assertSame("Should be equals", expected, result);
```

Also you should use PowerMock to mock constructors and static methods. To have deal with Logger, just add this code:

```
@BeforeClass
public static void setUpClass() {
    mockStatic(LoggerFactory.class);
    Logger logger = mock(Logger.class);
    when(LoggerFactory.getLogger(ApplySqlFileIfExistsChange.class)).thenReturn(logger);
}
```

Don't forget about annotations:

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest({LoggerFactory.class})
```

Try to read this doc [http://site.mockito.org/mockito/docs/current/org/mockito/Mockito.html](http://Mockito%20doc)

Comment: I was doing the same but its failing at when(initialContext.lookup(jndiName)).thenReturn(dataSource);.  I am getting java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException.

Comment: try @PrepareForTest({YourClass.class})